# ATR trailing stop implementation

Tags: mql5

I'm trying to implement an ATR trailing stop indicator in MQL5.  Compiler doesn't throw any errors, but nothing gets plotted on the chart and the indicator value doesn't change.

Stop Loss = ATR x multiplier

```
// ATR railing stop

#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 3
#property indicator_plots 1

// plot ATR stop
#property indicator_type1 DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1 Blue
#property indicator_style1 STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_label1 "ATR stop"

// input parameters for ATR stop
input int ATR_period = 14; // ATR length / period
input int ATR_stop_multiplier = 2; // ATR stop multiplier

// indicator buffers
double ATRstopBuffer[];
double ATRBuffer[];
double StopLossBuffer[];


// initializacion function
int OnInit()
{
    SetIndexBuffer(0, ATRstopBuffer, INDICATOR_DATA);
    SetIndexBuffer(1, ATRBuffer, INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
    SetIndexBuffer(2, StopLossBuffer, INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
    hATR = iATR(_Symbol,_Period, ATR_period);
    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

// iteration function
int OnCalculate(
                const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const int begin,
                const double& price[])
{
    if(rates_total < ATR_period) return(0);
    if(prev_calculated == 0)
    {
        ATRstopBuffer[0] = 0.0;
        StopLossBuffer[0] = 0.0;
    }
    int start;
    if(prev_calculated == 0) start = 1;
    else start = prev_calculated - 1;


    for(int i = start; i < rates_total; i++)
    {
        ATRBuffer[i] = iATR(NULL, 0, ATR_period);
        StopLossBuffer[i] = ATRBuffer[i] * ATR_stop_multiplier;
    }

    if(prev_calculated == 0) start = ATR_period + 1;
    for(int i = ATR_period - 1; i < rates_total; i++)
    {
        // if trend is up plot max(previous stop, current stop)
        if(price[i] >= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1] && price[i - 1] >= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1]) ATRstopBuffer[i] = MathMax(ATRstopBuffer[i - 1], (price[i] - StopLossBuffer[i]));

        // if trend is down plot min(previous stop, current stop)
        if(price[i] <= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1] && price[i - 1] <= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1]) ATRstopBuffer[i] = MathMin(ATRstopBuffer[i - 1], (price[i] + StopLossBuffer[i]));

        // if trend change up plot current stop
        if(price[i] >= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1]) ATRstopBuffer[i] = price[i] - StopLossBuffer[i];

        // if trend change down plot current stop
        if(price[i] <= ATRstopBuffer[i - 1]) ATRstopBuffer[i] = price[i] + StopLossBuffer[i];

    }
    return(rates_total);
}
```

Please refer to this link to see the indicator on TradingView: https://www.tradingview.com/script/mfBzZMD5-CDC-ATR-Trailing-Stop-V1/

Thanks!

Comment: Indicators cannot close deals or delete orders, you need an expert advisor to perform any trade actions

Comment: @DanielKniaz I know this! I want to build the indicator to later call it from an EA with iCustom()

Comment: @DanielKniaz or you think its better to jump straight to the EA and do the calculation there?

Comment: it is up to you of course, but seems it'd be better to have it in the EA directly unless you are going to try many different options and parameters. And your initial question was how to move SL, right? the answer is: no way, only ea/script can do that.

Comment: @DanielKniaz OK I will try to implement it directly in the EA, but I'd like to get it working as an indicator first if possible. Can you maybe point to what I'm doing wrong? the compiler throws no errors.